# Stream Builder with HTTP request is not working [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, http, stream, future, builder

I tried for the first time using Stream builder with HTTP requests. it is not updating data.
find below my code. Thanks for helping me!
/////////////////////////////////////////  //////////////////////////////////  ///////////////  ////////////////////   /////////////////////  ////////////////////  ///////////////////////////

```
    import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner:false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    body: StreamBuilder(
      stream: listMarkers,
      builder: (BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot<List<Coordonnees>> snapshot){
        switch (snapshot.connectionState){
          
          case ConnectionState.none:
            // TODO: Handle this case.
           // break;
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            // TODO: Handle this case.
           // break;
          case ConnectionState.active:
            return Center(child:CircularProgressIndicator());
           // break;
          case ConnectionState.done:
            List<Coordonnees>? mark=snapshot.data;
           return Center(
           child:Text('latitude: ${mark![0].latitude}',
           style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 30,
          )
          ),
        );
         //   break;
        }
      },
    ),
    );
  }

  List<Coordonnees> marqueurs=[];
  Future<List<Coordonnees>>  UpdateMarkers(String id) async{ 
   Map data = {
      'idligne': id,     
    };
     final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse("https://www.sirius-iot.eu/Dev/ESI/qitari2021/sarah.php?lignegps"),
      body: data);
      Map<String,dynamic> map=json.decode(response.body);
      List<dynamic> dataa = map['lignegps'];
      marqueurs.clear();
      for(var i in dataa)
      {  
        Coordonnees crd=Coordonnees(double.parse(i['latitude']),double.parse(i['longitude']),double.parse(i['vitesse']));
      marqueurs.add(crd);
      } 
      return marqueurs; 
 }

  Stream<List<Coordonnees>> get listMarkers async*{
   String id='1';
    yield await UpdateMarkers(id)  ;
 }
}
 
class Coordonnees{
  double latitude; 
  double longitude; 
  double vitesse;
  Coordonnees(this.latitude,this.longitude,this.vitesse);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `.asStream()` instead of manually yielding data which is awaited.

```
void main() {
  listMarkers.listen((coordinates) {
    print(coordinates);
  });
}

class Coordinates {
  int x;
  int y;
  
  Coordinates(this.x, this.y);
}

Future<List<Coordinates>> updateMarkers(String id) async{
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
  return [
    Coordinates(1,2)
  ];
}

Stream<List<Coordinates>> get listMarkers => updateMarkers('1').asStream();
```

Notice how elegant `Stream<List<Coordinates>> get listMarkers => updateMarkers('1').asStream();` is as compared to what you are doing. And hopefully it will solve your issue too.